# How can you find a reflection matrix about a given line, using matrix multiplication and the idea of composition of transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm reading Linear Algebra Done Wrong, and now there have been not 1 but 2 exercises that are extremely suggestive and indicative that there should be a way to do this. This being, to find a matrix that encodes a linear transformation of a vector reflected across the line of $y = -2x/3$, all in $\Bbb R^2$.

I have basically lost myself at this point in the weeds. I was able, for example, to in an earlier exercise multiply 2 rotation matrices and derive the trig identities for $\sin(a + b)$ and $\cos(a + b)$, which I then thought the similar idea of matrix multiplication would be applied right here. I still believe it has to be so! But I cannot for the life of me figure out actually which transformations to do to result in the final desired one.

Your help is greatly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 2):

So you have a vector $(x_1,y_1)^T$, and you want to find a matrix $M$ such that $(x_2,y_2)^T=M(x_1,y_1)^T$ is the reflection across $y=-2x/3$. So what does the reflection means? It means that the middle of the two points is on the line of reflection, and the line between those points is perpendicular to the reflection line.
The first condition can be written as $$\frac{y_1+y_2}2=-\frac 23\frac{x_1+x_2}2$$
The second condition means that the slope of the line between the two points is $-1/m$, where $m$ is the slope of the reflection line:$$\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=-\frac 1{-2/3}=\frac32$$
You now write $x_2$ and $y_2$ in terms of $x_1$ and $y_1$:$$x_2=m_{11}x_1+m_{12}y_1\\y_2=m_{21}x_1+m_{22}y_1$$
Then the matrix you are looking for has these coefficients.
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}m_{11}&m_{12}\\m_{21}&m_{22}\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: That's a rather interesting way to approach the problem! I wasn't thinking about it like that before, but actually this looks in a lot of ways more straightforward than the way I was set on doing it.

Comment: @Joseph From your comment on the other answer, your approach was to rotate first then apply the reflection around an axis. That matrix of reflection around the axis is a particular case of the above formulas, but with a more intuitive feel. So for reflection across the horizontal axis the first equation becomes $y_1+y_2=0$. The second equation is $x_2-x_1=0$. So $x_2=x_1$ and $y_2=-y_1$. That means that the reflection matrix across the horizontal is $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 2):

One strategy is to rotate the plane so that the line becomes $y=0$, apply the reflection in the $x$-axis, and then rotate back.

Let $\tan\theta=2/3$. Then the required matrix is $$\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\-\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos2\theta&-\sin2\theta\\-\sin2\theta&-\cos2\theta\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for this, this is literally *exactly* what I was forgetting/not understanding, the fact that having done that then you have to UNDO the rotation with another counter rotation transformation. Much love!